# Check if spawn is empty

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two spawn spots where a player will show up upon connection.

I need that, when one of the players connects on one of the spots, any other player will always spawn at the other spot.

Here's some visual in case it helps: https://goo.gl/Y0ohZC

Here is the code I'm using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnSpot : MonoBehaviour {

public int teamId=0;
public GameObject[] Spots; //Drag the spots in here (In the editor)
bool[] OccupiedSpawnSpots;

//Using Photon Networking
void OnJoinedRoom()
{
    //Request the recent OccupiedSpawnSpots List
    PhotonView.RPC("RequestList", PhotonTargets.MasterClient, PhotonNetwork.player); 
}

//In "RequestList" the MasterClient sends his List of the SpawnSpots 
//by calling "ReceiveList"
[RPC]
void RequestList(PhotonPlayer player)
{
    PhotonView.RPC("ReceiveList", PhotonTargets.All, player, OccupiedSpawnSpots);
}


[RPC]
void ReceiveList(PhotonPlayer Sender, bool[] ListOfMasterClient)
{
    OccupiedSpawnSpots = ListOfMasterClient;

    //Get the free one
    if (OccupiedSpawnSpots[0] == false)
    {
        //Spawn player at 0
        if (Sender == PhotonNetwork.player)
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("PlayerController", Spots[0].transform.position);
        OccupiedSpawnSpots[0] = true;
    } 
    else
    {
        //Spawn player at 1
        if (Sender == PhotonNetwork.player)
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("PlayerController", Spots[1].transform.position);
        OccupiedSpawnSpots[1] = true;
    }
}
```

The errors given are:

> Assets/Scripts/SpawnSpot.cs(14,28): error CS0120: An object reference
>   is required to access non-static member `PhotonView.RPC(string,
>   PhotonPlayer, params object[])'
>
> Assets/Scripts/SpawnSpot.cs(22,28): error CS0120: An object reference
>   is required to access non-static member `PhotonView.RPC(string,
>   PhotonPlayer, params object[])'
>
> Assets/Scripts/SpawnSpot.cs(36,47): error CS1501: No overload for
>   method `Instantiate' takes`3' arguments
>
> Assets/Scripts/SpawnSpot.cs(43,47): error CS1501: No overload for
>   method `Instantiate' takes`3' arguments

Thanks in advance, IC

Comment: On the face of it, that code looks like it's already handling the functionality you want, is it not working? If not can you give some detail as to how it's going wrong?

Comment: Here are the two errors I'm getting when I try to run: https://goo.gl/MNrcl1

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error messages in it, preferably as text instead of a screenshot as I can't see the full message for the first error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to call an instance function using a static reference.  instead of doing `PhotonView.RPC("RequestList", PhotonTargets.MasterClient, PhotonNetwork.player);` 
you need to create a reference to an PhatorView object, and then call the RPC function on it.

```
public PhotonView photonView;
void OnJoinedRoom()
{
     if(photonView == null)
     {
         photonView = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
     }

     //Request the recent OccupiedSpawnSpots List
     PhotonView.RPC("RequestList", PhotonTargets.MasterClient, PhotonNetwork.player); 
}
```

you should have a PhotonView object on the same GameObject that this script is on, or assign a reference to a PhotonView in the editor.

That should fix your problems, but I think you should look into compiler errors and how to to fix them.  In Unity3D if you double click the error in the console it will take you to the line that isn't compiling.  It also tends to give you a pretty good hint as to why it isn't compiling.

your error was this

"Assets/Scripts/SpawnSpot.cs(14,28): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `PhotonView.RPC(string, PhotonPlayer, params object[])'"

which means that you need an object in order to call this function.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, I think I got it better now! About the compiler errors, those and many others, I definitely want to learn how to fix all my own stuff, but I'm still newbie at this, so that's why I wanted help in "how to" solve it. Thanks again!

Comment: Anytime, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The third and fourth errors are because you are calling [`Instantiate`](http://doc-api.exitgames.com/en/pun/current/pun/doc/class_photon_network.html#a843d9f62d28ab123c83291c1e6bb857d) with only 2 arguments, but it takes at least 4. Include the rotation of the GameObject you're trying to instantiate, and a group number:

```
PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("PlayerController", Spots[0].transform.position, Quaternion.identity, 0);
```

Note that you may not want the [identity quaternion](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-identity.html), so you may need to change this. Also I'm not familiar with PhotonNetwork so 0 may not be an advisable group.

Comment: Here are the current errors: http://pastebin.com/Hz6uuy1Q. This is already after including the argument fix you found, making the current script being this: http://pastebin.com/xGjhSQ0Z

Comment: I've updated my answer which should solve the last 2 errors you're getting. Colton's answer looks like it should solve the other problems.